# Print last word if its last letter is "r"

Tags: text-processing

How may I print the last word on a line if its last letter is, for example, `r`?

```
I am reading the book
I am reading the letter
```

The result:

```
letter
```

I work with bash linux, Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
$ awk '/r$/ { print $NF }' file
letter
```

This uses `awk` to test whether each line ends with the character `r`.  The test is carried out using a regular expression, `r$`.  This expression matches only if the last character is `r`.  If it matches, the last whitespace-delimited field, `$NF`, is printed.

Note that this assumes that there is no trailing whitespace at the end of the line and that by "word", you mean any string of characters delimited by some whitespace.

---

Using `sed`:

```bash
$ sed -e '/r$/!d' -e 's/.* //' file
letter
```

This first skips any line that does not end with an `r` (this is the first expression).  It then uses a substitution command to remove everything up to and including the last space character on any remaining line.  Whatever is left is then outputted.

Again, this assumes no trailing space characters on any line and that a "word" is any string delimited by spaces.

---

Using `rev`+`cut`+`grep` (I'm not seriously suggesting you would use this):

```bash
$ rev file | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev | grep 'r$'
letter
```

This reverses each individual line using the non-standard utility `rev`.  It then extracts the first space-separated string using `cut` and reverses the resulting words to their original order.  The `grep` utility is then used to extract any word that ends with `r`, using a familiar regular expression.

Comment: In case the line ends with whitespace, `$NF ~ /r$/`

Comment: Thank you very much, best regards. mr.kusalananda and mr.glenn

Comment: Maybe also `grep -oE '\b\S+r$'`

Comment: @jesse_b Nah, if we've already said words are space-delimited, we don't have to go further and demand that they are two characters long or longer. What if they had asked for `a` instead? It's a complete word. Also, know what type of regular expressions you're using!  :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda: huh?

Comment: @jesse_b `-E` for extended regular expressions, and then feeding it with `\b` and `\S`?  Surely you meant `-P`?

Comment: @Kusalananda: maybe, works with -E for me though.

Comment: @jesse_b You young people and your GNU tools... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.words.[*-1] andthen .put if .grep(/ r $ /);'  file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -ne '$_ = .words.[*-1]; .put if .grep(/ r $ /);'  file
```

You might want to consider a Perl-family language for this problem. Using Raku above, an input file is read linewise using the `-ne` non-autoprinting flags. The input is broken into `words` (i.e. broken on whitespace), and the last element (i.e. word) `.[*-1]` is retained. In the first example, `andthen` is used to reload the last word into `$_`, which is Raku's topic variable. In the second example, `$_` is simply assigned the `.words.[*-1]` value.

From here a simple `grep` returns the entire word if a match is found to the `/ r $ /` regex. Note: whitespace is generally tolerated within Raku regexes, making them more readable.

Sample Input:

```
I am reading the book
I am reading the letter
```

Sample Output:

```
letter
```

Raku links below, including `word` definition.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/words
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org